# CAS ReST - Add Service

Tags: java, rest, api, cas

I am trying to [add a new service](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.0.x/protocol/REST-Protocol.html#add-service) to CAS via their ReST API. First it said that "Attribute name and/or value must be configured". Then I added attribute name and attribute value with some junk value to the CAS properties. Now it says that the Request could not be authenticated. This is how I am making a request

POST

```
localhost:8443/cas/v1/services/add/TGT-1-CHZrXD5XAulLuUgoMDQudTe6j16k5k41XBQH640wHFhbuq9QWY-xoadmin
```

BODY

```
{
    "@class" : "org.apereo.cas.services.RegexRegisteredService",
    "serviceId" : "service name",
    "name" : "xosso",
    "id" : 2,
    "evaluationOrder" : 10,
    "proxyPolicy" : {
         "@class" : "org.apereo.cas.services.RegexMatchingRegisteredServiceProxyPolicy",
         "pattern" : "^https?://.*"
    }
}
```

PS : I tried sending it part of the URL, still it says the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add first the header application/x-www-form-urlencoded
also for the value and key you have to add on of the attributes keys from your user attributes and the expected attribute value 
for me for example i put :

```
cas.rest.attributeName=memberOf
cas.rest.attributeValue=cn=Administrator,....
cas.rest.throttler=neverThrottle
```